# Macbook Air Bootcamp Assistant leads to Windows 10 install error 0xc0000001

Tags: bootcamp, windows, partition

Finally managed to get my partition to work, but now when installing Windows 10 Home, Windows 10 Home N, or Windows 8.1, none will work and I am prompted with the error code 0xc0000001 loop. Please help. Here is the diskutil list of my drive.[image: Drives after partition and install failure]

Comment: This error means a system file was corrupted. Can you remove the partition using bootcamp and try to install it again?

Comment: did you ever find a fix to this?

Comment: @GordonBeingessner It turns out I was using a OWC SSD, which was unable to run Bootcamp. Went through a lot of trouble until I finally called them and they informed me that their drive is not compatible.

Answer (score 1):

The partition looks right.  Did you go through the BootCamp creator to create the installation media?  Drivers for the Disk Controller are added to the installation media by BootCamp.

See https://discussions.apple.com/thread/8276897 for an explanation.
See https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201468 for Apple's official instructions.

Comment: I think High Sierra has an issue with bootcamp, so I'm trying to install the latest update for Mojave, which came out July 22nd, 2019. Hopefully that will do the trick.

Comment: Let us know how it goes...

Comment: Got the newest update for Mojave going but still no luck. Still falls into reset loop.

Comment: is /dev/disk2 your installation media?  That should be UEFI not FAT32.  How did you make the disk?

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out I was using a OWC SSD that was not compatible with bootcamp. Got a full refund but not worth the amount of trouble I went through trying to troubleshoot this issue.